# Pointwise adjointness theorem

Tags: category-theory, solution-verification, adjoint-functors

I'm confused in the way [Barr and Wells](http://www.math.mcgill.ca/triples/Barr-Wells-ctcs.pdf) proof the uniqueness of adjoints. Once they prove that using Yoneda lemma the two candidates $F,F'$ to be adjoint to some functor $U$ satisfy $F A \cong F' A$ for any $A$ they conclude by saying that the naturality of the isomorphism is a consequence of the following theorem:

> Let $\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}$ be categories and $U: \mathcal{B} \to \mathcal{A}$ be a functor. Suppose for each object $A$ of $\mathcal{A}$ there is an object $FA$ of $\mathcal{B}$ such that $Hom(FA, \cdot)$ is naturally equivalent to $Hom(A,U \cdot)$ as a functor from $\mathcal{B}$ to $Set$. Then the definition of $F$ on objects can be extended to arrows in such a way that $F$ becomes a functor and is left adjoint to $U$.

I'm assuming naturally equivalent means naturally isomorphic.

**Question**

Is the following proof correct?

**Proof**

Let $f:A \to A'$ be an arrow in $\mathcal{A}^{op}$ and denote the $n_A: Hom(FA, \cdot) \stackrel{\cong}{\to} Hom(A,U \cdot)$. Then we have the diagram:

[image]

If an arrow $Hom(FA',B) \to Hom(FA,B)$ makes the diagram commute it is necessarily: $$\phi(f,B) = n_A \circ Hom(f,UB) \circ n_{A'}^{-1}$$ But actually, $\phi(f,\cdot): Hom(FA',\cdot) \to Hom(FA,\cdot)$ is a natural transformation in $B$ since $n_A, n_{A'}$ and $Hom(f,U \cdot)$ are natural in $B$. By the Yoneda lemma, there exists a unique $B \in Hom(F A', F A)$ such that $Y(B) = Hom(B, \cdot) = \phi(f, \cdot)$. We define $F f = B: FA \to FA'$ as a morphism in $\mathcal{C}^{op}$.

We check that $F$ defined in this way is a functor.

$\phi(id_A, \cdot) = n_A \circ Hom(id_A,\cdot) \circ n_{A}^{-1} 
 =  n_A \circ n_A^{-1} = id$

$
 \phi(f , \cdot) \circ \phi(g, \cdot) = n_A \circ Hom(f, \cdot) \circ n_{A'}^{-1} \circ n_{A'} \circ Hom(g,\cdot) \circ n_{A''}^{-1} 
 = n_A \circ Hom(f,\cdot) \circ Hom(g,\cdot) \circ n_{A''}^{-1} 
 = n_A \circ Hom(f \circ g, \cdot) \circ n_{A''}^{-1} 
 = \phi(f \circ g, \cdot)
$

It remains to check that $F$ is left adjoint to $U$. However, the above diagram states precisely the naturality in $A$ of the isomorphism while by hypothesis we have the naturality in $B$. These two lead to the conclusion that $F$ built in this way is left adjoint to $U$.

**Question**

My conclusion is that up to the choice of $n$ above, $F$ is uniquely determined. So this is indeed a proof of the uniqueness of adjoints up to isomorphism. Is that right?

Comment: I don't think it's a consequence of the theorem, but of the proof. Or rather, of a stronger theorem, which says that given the natural isomorphism $Hom(FA, \cdot) \to Hom(A, U \cdot)$, there is a *unique* way to extend $F$ on arrows making $F$ adjoint to $U$. The statement is not difficult to show. But I think there are better ways of proving the uniqueness of adjoints

Comment: @MaximeRamzi thanks for your comment. if you have a reference for this claim that's very helpful.

Comment: I don't know a specific reference, it's probably everywhere or nowhere - but it's not hard to prove in any case.

Comment: @MaximeRamzi I have written a proof. To me it looks like $F$ can be extended in a unique way up to natural isomorphism (probably that's what you meant...) in particular, there is a choice of natural isomorphism between $Hom(FA, \cdot) \cong Hom(A, U \cdot)$

Comment: Ah yes, I did explicitly say "given the natural isomorphism" ! It is part of the data from which you construct $F$ *uniquely*